# How to send URL parameter from angularJS to MVC action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router, parameter-passing

> I am using the state provider for mapping the urls , and the following is my AngularJS code.

```
 .state('uimenucategories', {
        url: "/MenuCategory.html",
        templateUrl: "/AppMenuMaker/MenuCategory",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Menu Category'},
        controller: "MenuCategoryController",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                    name: 'MetronicApp',
                    files: [
                           'js/controllers/MenuCategoryController.js',


                    ]
                }]);
            }] 
        }
    })
```

> I want to take parameters from the URL to pass them to the action before rendering the view

```
    public ActionResult MenuCategory(int? CategoryID){}
```

any help for how I can send them from URL like this `Dashboard/Index#/ViewMenuCategories.html?ID=1`
 ?

Comment: I am in iphone i will try to help you:  templateUrl: function(stateParams){ return '/AppMenuMaker/MenuCategory?categoryId=' + stateParams.id; }. I dont remember exact name is service is stateParams.

Comment: @fabiosilvalima I am getting this error 'Unknown provider: $stateParams'

Comment: like i said if stateParams is right name. I will chek thia today at night

Comment: @fabiosilvalima thanks

Comment: It worked with me like that , with no need to inject a service , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you hit url 'Dashboard/Index#/ViewMenuCategories.html?ID=1' on browser, angular will search for a template on '/AppMenuMaker/MenuCategory?CategoryID=1'.

I think the code would be:

```
.state('uimenucategories', {
    url: "/MenuCategory.html",
    templateUrl: ['$location', function($location){
        return '/AppMenuMaker/MenuCategory?CategoryID=' + $location.search().ID || '';
        }
    }],
    data: {pageTitle: 'Menu Category'},
    controller: "MenuCategoryController",
    resolve: {
        deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
            return $ocLazyLoad.load([{
                name: 'MetronicApp',
                files: [
                       'js/controllers/MenuCategoryController.js',


                ]
            }]);
        }] 
    }
})
```

Controller / Action:

```
public ActionResult MenuCategory(int? CategoryID)
{
    return View('');
}
```

> You will need to reference Angular Route in your app to use **$location** service.

Comment: Thanks alot !! but I get error 'Unknown provider: $location'

Comment: Did you referenced the angular route .js file? could share the file name?

Comment: I have those services injected : MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$location', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$location) {
    // Redirect any unmatched url

Comment: @Hana download angular route library and put together other angular libraries angular-route.js

Comment: @Hana inject the $location inside templateUrl function and not in .config() function. Your config function must ge that: MetronicApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {}

Comment: It worked with me as you said before in the comment     url: "/MenuCategory.html/:id?",
                    templateUrl:function(params){
                        return "/AppMenuMaker/MenuCategory?CategoryID="+params.id
                    },